# Decode JSON in Visual Basic 2010 Express

Tags: arrays, json, vb.net

I am just learning the basics in VB 2010, and I am trying to design a program to maintain a database. I have a JSON string in the database that contains a list of image files and their relevant ID numbers. This is in JSON as a website also uses this data.
The example code is

```
[{"ID": 0, "Path": "Image0.jpg"},{"ID": 1, "Path": "Image1.jpg"}, {"ID": 2, "Path": "Image2.jpg"},{"ID": 3, "Path": "Image3.jpg"}]
```

I have tried using JSON.NET, but I am a novice and don't know why it isn't working.

I wish for there to be a way I can return the image files, for example in php `$DecodedArray[0]` would work, I am looking for a way to replicate this in Visual Basic.

```
Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization
Module Module1

Public Class Target
    Public ID, Image As String
End Class

Sub Main()
    Console.Clear()
    Dim ser As New JavaScriptSerializer()
    Dim input As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("JSONFile.txt")
    '[{"ID": 0, "Path": "Image0.jpg"},{"ID": 1, "Path": "Image1.jpg"}, {"ID": 2, "Path": "Image2.jpg"},{"ID": 3, "Path": "Image3.jpg"}]
    Console.WriteLine(input)
    Console.WriteLine()
    Dim output As Target = ser.Deserialize(Of Target)(input)
    Console.Write(output.ID.0)
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub

End Module
```

With this code, I would like the output to be Image0.jpg

Note, I cannot upgrade from Visual Basic 2010 Express

Comment: So... why is this tagged PHP?

Comment: why do you say json.net has failed?

Comment: @DanielA.White It has failed multiple times, with my multiple attempts. It is usually a conversion error of some sort of that it 'cannot access child value'

Comment: You'll need to post your VB code.

Comment: @JoeEnos I've posted my code, along with what I would like the output to be

Comment: That JSON looks like a mess.  Using ID numbers as properties is HORRIBLE.  I would suggest you construct a JSON object with real properties and use an array for compacting it:  `[{"ID": 1, "Path": "Image1.jpg"}, {"ID": N, "Path": "ImageN.jpg"}]

Comment: @Dan-o, so if I change the JSON, is it easier to decode and use?

Comment: @JoshLukeBlease: Yes.  And it looks as if Joe has you covered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your JSON has numeric keys instead of expected keys, it would be difficult to define a custom type to match it. I believe your best bet is to deserialize into a `Dictionary(Of String, String)` - this will deserialize properly, and you can read through the dictionary to get your items.

So:

```
Dim output = ser.Deserialize(Of Dictionary(Of String, String))(input)
For Each key As String In output.Keys
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", key, output(key))
Next
```

Normally when you define a regular type, you'd have to know the names of the JSON properties. Given your `Target` class, your JSON would actually look like:

```
[
    { "ID":"0", "Image":"Image0.jpg" },
    { "ID":"1", "Image":"Image1.jpg" },
    { "ID":"2", "Image":"Image2.jpg" }
]
```

And it would deserialize into an array of Target objects, rather than a single one. But if you're stuck with the JSON that you've got, the `Dictionary` is the way to go.

If you're able to use the cleaner JSON from here, your code is just about right. You just deserialize into an array instead, and you can access elements of that array. So:

```
Dim output = ser.Deserialize(Of Target())(input)
For i As Integer = 0 To output.GetUpperBound(0)
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", output(i).ID, output(i).Image)
Next
```

Comment: What code would I use then If I was to use the cleaner JSON? I can change the code of the website to use the new format.

Comment: @JoshLukeBlease Edited with what you'd need to change.